# EvaluateExpession in ExpressionBuilder

Tags: .net, asp.net

I need to implement own ExpressionBuilder. I know how to implement GetCodeExpression() so I'm able to do in markup:
    <%$ OwnBuilder: MyMethod(param) %>

But now I need to implement also the EvaluateExpression to return the result of my own method (to do something like <%$ OwnBuilder: param %>. How should the EvaluateExpression method be implemented? Something like this??:

```
public override object EvaluateExpression(object target, BoundPropertyEntry entry, object parsedData,     ExpressionBuilderContext context)
{
    return OwnExpressionBuilderPrivateMethod(entry.Expression);
}
```

and what about the GetCodeExpression()?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [EvaluateExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.expressionbuilder.evaluateexpression.aspx) method is used when the [CompilationMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.compilationmode.aspx) is set to 'Never' and the ExpressionBuilder supports evalutions by overriding the [SupportsEvaluate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.expressionbuilder.supportsevaluate.aspx) property (and returning 'true').

If you don't plan to support theses no-compile pages, the SupportsEvaluate returns false by default, so just implement an EvaluateExpression method that returns null.

In our ExpressionBuilder implementation, we support the <%$ OwnBuilder: param %> type of expression using the [GetCodeExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.expressionbuilder.getcodeexpression.aspx) method.